# Rigidbody manipulation not working on Y axis? (Unity3D 2020.1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is weird.

I've been learning more in depth about Rigidbody, and I can't for the life of me, make it jump. I'm copying exactly what I see on youtube tutorials, and  it works for the youtubers, but not for me.

In more C# english - I was trying to .AddForce(ForceMode.TriedEverything) on the y axis, via user Input. It won't work consistently. sometimes it's higher, sometimes lower, most times nothing at all. this is weird. and I didn't even put isGrounded or any other limitation. Simply "addforce if user input". This is case no 1

Case 2 is much simpler, and NEVER works: it's based on setting the velocity to a new vector with only the y axis manipulated. I'll sharethe code. the “jumpForce” is set to 12, but i've tried 500 too. no difference. This case does have a “grounded” condition, but it didn't work without it as well. Anyway, both print statements get executed.

Both cases were tested in Update and in FixedUpdate, no differences.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask layerMask = default;
    public bool grounded;

    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 12f;

    

    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {   
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;


        Vector3 movePosition = transform.right * x + transform.forward * y;
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(movePosition.x, rb.velocity.y, movePosition.z);

        grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.z), 0.4f, layerMask);
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)&& grounded)
        {
            print("reached if statement");
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);
            print("jumpingjumping");
        }

        rb.velocity = newPosition;

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

    }


}
```

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order of your code. You are setting the newPosition variable before the jump statement so the y velocity is 0, then you are setting the y velocity to the jump velocity but after that you set the velocity to the newPosition which still has a velocity of 0 because it was set before the jump statement. Here is the working code:

```
    public LayerMask layerMask = default;
public bool grounded;

[SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 7f;
[SerializeField] float jumpForce = 12f;



Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;


    Vector3 movePosition = transform.right * x + transform.forward * y;

    grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.z), 0.4f, layerMask);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
    {
        print("reached if statement");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);
        print("jumpingjumping");
    }

    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(movePosition.x, rb.velocity.y, movePosition.z);
    rb.velocity = newPosition;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{

}
```

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Hey man, thanks! I fixed it with this type of code, but for some reason never saw your comment, I thought the thread died :/